# Grab a discord token by verifying

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py

I want to know how to grab a discord token when a user is verifying on my server. So that the tiktok is either sent to a channel or saved in a file.

I have tryed searching for a code for this but I could find any. I'd very appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by discord token?

Comment: Every account has a token. You can use it to access the account without knowing the email or password

Comment: you can't, here is everything that you can get from a member https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/GuildMember

Answer (score 1):

Discord has certain limitations in the API, one of them is this. For privacy, it does not let bots access user tokens.

Comment: I have seen this multiple times. Bigger NSFW servers use a verify system but when you verify, a message will be sent by you in every channel on every server. So it has to work

Comment: That doesn't work like that, what they do is generate a QR code, which if you scan it with your mobile, will give that BOT access to your account since it's as if you had logged in on any device. Once you access your account, it sends an MD to everyone. discord itself has nothing to do with this topic since its API is not used